# Uniform scaling for multiple edges?

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms, edges

I was making a quadball, and in the way I do it, I take a cube, cut one edgeloop on each axis, and then individually scale each edgeloop to make the cube into a quadball. But I was thinking, to make the perfect quadball, I'd need to be able to scale each edgeloop to the exact same degree. Is there a way to do this?

Please do not recommend other ways to make quadballs, just please tell me if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Comment: Cast modifier -> sphere with 1.0 strength is the usual solution, but that will move your corner vertices.

Comment: for exact scale, use numeric values, ie, S1.2<enter>

Comment: @Marty Fouts ‘S’ as in the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: yes.  The keyboard shortcut can take a numeric value followed by the Enter K to scale by exactly that value.